# How to perform a large migration?

Tags: migration

If I want to migrate the `Balance::Locks` to a new structure.
Imagine there are millions of accounts in the storage.

This is what I came out. Is this the right way? Split them into multiple blocks. If yes, how can I record the pos?

```rust
storage OldLocks
storage NewLocks
storage LastPos

fn on_new_block() {
    LastPos::put(migrate_from(LastPos::get()));
}

// Aka the locks' `getter` during the migration
fn lock_of(account) -> Amount {
    let mut locks = [];

    if let Some(lock) = NewLocks::get(account) {
        locks.append(lock);
    }
    if let Some(lock) = OldLocks::get(account) {
        locks.append(lock);
    }

    return locks.cal_total_lock_amount();
}
```

Furthermore, what if I want to keep using the old name? I don't want to break the API. `move_prefix(b"Locks", b"OldLocks")` first, does this take too much weights?

Comment: The docs go into this a bit - if it's just a few blocks then the scheduler can help: https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/parachains/runtime-upgrades/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 years. We have a built-in multi-block migration method now!

Check https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/1781 for more detail.

Answer (score 12):

This is basically the correct approach.

There isn't actually any need to record the position: you should be removing items from `OldLocks` and inserting equivalents into `NewLocks`. You can stop the migration once `OldLocks` is empty. As long as you can guarantee that migration will remove at least one item from `OldLocks` and that your runtime never introduces any items into `OldLocks` then this will complete in a finite time.

See the `pallet-xcm` in Polkadot for an example on multi-block migrations.

Comment: What if I want to keep using the old name? I don't want to break the API.
`move_prefix(b"Locks", b"OldLocks")` Does this works?

Comment: I think so, move_prefix is O(1) operation, try it(Before launch, test it locally and in your own testnet).

Comment: From looking at the code of `move_prefix`; it is at least `O(n)`. AFAIK It *could* be implemented in `O(1)`, but currently there is no host function for that. In any case, it is better to benchmark migrations - especially for parachains.